# Pass multiline html as argument via php system() 

Tags: php, python, shell, exec

Due to reasons that are have nothing to do with the actual question, I need to call and use an external script via PHP to perform a string replacement on a complete html document. The replacement strings and the source code need to be passded to this script via php exec(). For this example, I have used a simple python script to take over the replacement.

PHP script looks like this:

```
$source = file_get_contents("somehtmlfile.html");
$replaceString = "Some text in the HTML doc";
$replaceTo = "Some other text";
$parsedString = system("python replace.py $replaceString $replaceTo $source", $retval);
print ("Done:" .$mystring);
```

Then the Python script will do the following:

```
import sys
import string
dataFrom = sys.argv[1];
dataTo = sys.argv[2];
dataSourceCode = sys.argv[3];
rep = dataSourceCode.replace(dataFrom, dataTo);
print rep;
```

The problem is that I can't pass the complete html source as an argument to the shell, at least not in the way shown above. From what I understood, while the html code gets passed to the shell it interpretes some sections as commands (multiline could be an issue here I suppose).

The output I receive from the script :

sh: cannot open !DOCTYPE: No such file
sh: cannot open html: No such file
sh: cannot open head: No such file
sh: cannot open title: No such file

... (this goes on)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't quite remember how quotes worked in php, but you probably have to do `system('python replace.py "$replaceString" "$replaceTo" "$source"')`, you wrap the arguments in double quotes.

Comment: Also note that you don't need the semicolon after each line in python.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it doesent work :-/ (btw single quotes don't allow variable interpretation in PHP so this example would beed to be rewritten like this : system('python replace.py "'.$replaceString.'" "'.$replaceTo.'" "'.$source.'"'). Thanks

Comment: Can't you just escape the quotes in php: `system("python replace.py \"$replaceString\" \"$replaceTo\" \"$source\"")`?

Comment: That would have the same effect. Not to forget, the html source is also full of doulble quotes (and single quotes sometimes) so this also creates a conflict.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought about the quotes in the html. Couldn't you use [this](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to escape the html, like `system('python replace.py "'.$replaceString.'" "'.$replaceTo.'" '.escapeshellarg($source))`. I assume that `$replaceString` and `$replaceTo` are safe strings, otherwise you also have to escape them.

Comment: After all is was an issue with quotes. Only that I have to use single quotes for the params and not double quotes :) system("python replace.py '$replaceString' '$replaceTo' '$source'") Maybe you can add this as an answer so I can accept it since the idea is correct.

Comment: Added it as an answer, glad that we sorted it out and that it is working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because there are spaces and quotes in the html text that you pass as an argument, so it is seen as multiple arguments. To solve this, you have to put quotes around the arguments.
The correct code is `$parsedString = system("python replace.py '$replaceString' '$replaceTo' '$source'", $retval);`